# Where can I read Muvāyirappaṭi Guruparamparāprabhāva in English?

Tags: ramanujacharya, resource

I would like to read the Muvāyirappaṭi Guruparamparāprabhāva, the biography of the great Vaishnava acharya, Sri Ramanujachaya, in English. Can anyone provide me a link for it?

Comment: preferable to do kalakshepam under acharya. these works are very .. how to say .. 'intimate', and if one reads without proper bhava (humility, emotion), which is very hard to get without sitting under a teacher's shadow, its essence is dwindled.. like eating an ice-cream after it has melted.

Comment: @ram How do I get an acharya?

Comment: where do u live ? Out of 74 simhasanadhipathis established by Swami, few exist today. If you go to your nearest (or dearest) elders, they might point you to the nearest (or dearest) mutt or ashram. Approach one of the kainkarya-paras (brahmins working in that institution), and ask for an audience with the matadhipathi (yati/sanyasi). Basically, start with your first acharyas, your parents.

Comment: @ram No Sri Vaishnava mutts or ashrams here in Kolkata unfortunately

Comment: I got this , hope it is of some use. 
  http://acharya.org/bk/pb/AG/LifeOfRamanujacharya-AG.pdf